# MergeSort w/ Custom Functions

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, mergesort

Please review my implementation of `mergesort`:

```
mergesort' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergesort' []     = []
mergesort' xs = merge' (sort' fst', sort' snd')
   where fst' = take half xs
         snd' = drop half xs
         half = len `div` 2 
         len = length xs

merge' :: (Ord a) => ([a], [a]) -> [a]
merge' ([], [])      = []
merge' ([], ys)      = ys
merge' (xs, [])      = xs 
merge' (x:xs, y:ys) = if x < y then x : merge' (xs, y:ys) else y : merge'(x:xs, ys)

sort' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort' []     = []
sort' (x:xs) = m : sort' rest
  where m = foldl (\acc x -> if x < acc then x else acc) x xs
        rest = filterOne' (/= m) (x:xs)

filterOne' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterOne' _ []     = []
filterOne' f (x:xs) = if not $ f x then xs else x : filterOne' f xs
```

If it doesn't adhere to the `mergesort` algorithm, please let me know.

Also, is there a Haskell library function for my `filterOne'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't mergesort! `sort'` is a different sorting algorithm entirely, so you end up only performing one merge step before kicking it over to (I believe) selection sort.

First let's address the easy stylistic issues so we have a good base to work from. The primary issue is that the argument passed to `merge'` is a tuple, which is unnecessary, uncurried, and not very Haskell-y. I'll also drop the extra apostrophes where there isn't an actual naming conflict with the Prelude. We use as-patterns to avoid reconstructing patterns we just deconstructed. And let's just toss `sort'` and `filterOne'`, they're not part of the solution!

```
mergesort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergesort []     = []
mergesort xs     = merge (??? left) (??? right)
    where half = (length xs) `div` 2
          left  = take half xs
          right = drop half xs

merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] []                 = []
merge xs []                 = xs
merge [] ys                 = ys
merge xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys) = if x <= y then x : merge xs yss else y : merge xss ys
                                 -- ^ Less than *or equal* so our sort is stable
```

One question is what goes in for the `???` where we used to call `sort'`? Well, `mergesort`!

One more complex issue of style is the usage of `if` in `merge`. Top-level `if`s are better represented as guards in Haskell, it's easier to extend guards and their usage is more idiomatic.

```
merge xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys) | x <= y    = x : merge xs yss
                            | otherwise = y : merge xss ys
```

One small change we can make is adding another base case to `mergesort` to account for lists of length 1, which are by definition sorted.

```
mergesort xs@[x] = xs
```

There's only one more improvement I'd make to this, and that's to call `splitAt` rather than `take` and `drop` in `mergesort`. Using both `take` and `drop` leads to walking half the list twice in each recursive step where we can walk it only once by doing some more bookkeeping. `splitAt` takes an index to split a list at, and returns the prefix and remainder just like using `take` and `drop` separately would.

So putting all of that together, here's the final version.

```
mergesort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergesort []     = []
mergesort xs@[x] = xs
mergesort xs     = merge (mergesort left) (mergesort right)
    where half = (length xs) `div` 2
          (left, right) = splitAt half xs

merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] []                 = []
merge xs []                 = xs
merge [] ys                 = ys
merge xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys) | x <= y    = x : merge xs yss
                            | otherwise = y : merge xss ys
```

Comment: when I re-implemented after peeking at your answer, I first ran into a non-convergent (never completed) result since I hadn't properly handled the `mergesort [x]` case.

Answer (score 1):

For your `merge` function, you can simplify it a bit using [as-patterns](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#.40). This allows you to bind both `x`, `xs`, and the full list to a name:

```
merge' (xs'@(x:xs), ys'@(y:ys)) = if x < y then x : merge' (xs, ys') else y : merge (xs', ys)
```

This basically says "Use the name `xs'` to refer to `(x:xs)`".

The closest thing in `Data.List` to your `filterOne'` function is probably [span](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aspan). This can be used as follows:

```
filterOne' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterOne' f xs = fst z ++ (tail $ snd z)
    where z = span f xs
```